# Limit of a solution of a Euler Lagrange differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Consider the Lagrangian: $$L_N=\frac{\dot q _1 ^2+\dot q _2 ^2}{2}-Nq_2 ^2-U(q_1,q_2,t),$$ with it's Euler-Lagrange equations $\frac{\text d }{\text d t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}=0$. In the book I'm reading, [“Mathematical methods of classical mechanics”](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387968903), the author makes the following statement (my paraphrase):

> Let $\varphi ^N =(\varphi _1 ^N,\varphi _2 ^N)$ be the solution of the equations of motion
>   with initial conditions $$q_1(0)=q_1^0, \quad \dot q_1 (0)=\dot q _1 ^0\quad q_2(0)=0, \quad \dot q_2 (0)=0$$
>   Then, there exists the limit $$\lim _{N\to \infty}\varphi _1 ^N (t)=\psi (t).$$
>   The limit function satisfies the Euler Lagrange equation, with Lagrangian $$L=\frac{\dot q_1 ^2}{2}-U^*(q_1,t), \qquad U^*(q_1,t)=U(q_1,0,t).$$

There's no proof, only a footnote that says:

> The proof is based on the fact that, by energy conservation, $|q_2|\leq \frac{c}{\sqrt N}$.

My first question is: what kind of convergence is he claiming? Pointwise? Uniform in $t$? My intuition is that (under appropriate assumptions on $U$, of course) one should be able to prove uniform convergence in every interval $-T\leq t\leq T$.

My second question is: how can I actually prove the claim? I tried to sketch a proof and got stuck at a point.

**Attempt.** Let $t>0$, $\varepsilon >0$, define $\psi $ by $$\dfrac{\text d}{\text d t}\dfrac{\partial L^*}{\partial \dot q_1}-\dfrac{\partial L^*}{\partial q_1}|_{q=\psi (t),\ \dot q=\dot \psi (t)}=0$$
with the same initial data as above (assume the solution is unique). Then $$|\psi (t)-\varphi _1 ^N(t)|\leq |\ddot \psi (\tau)-\ddot \varphi _1 ^N (\tau)|t^2=|f(\psi (\tau),0,\tau)-f(\varphi _1 ^N (\tau),\varphi _2 ^N(\tau),\tau)|t^2 ,$$
for some $0<\tau<t$, $f=\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_1}$ (the first equation can be obtained by Lagrange theorem and could have a $0.5$ before). I know at this point I should use the littleness of $\varphi _2 ^N$, so I use the following trick: $$|\psi (t)-\varphi _1 ^N(t)|\leq |f(\psi (\tau),0,\tau)-f(\varphi _1 ^N (\tau),0,\tau)|t^2+|f(\varphi _1 ^N(\tau),0,\tau)-f(\varphi _1 ^N (\tau),\varphi _2 ^N (\tau),\tau)|t^2.$$

At this point I'm stuck. If I'm able to show that for all $N>N_0$ there exists $M$ such that $|\varphi _1 ^N(\tau)|\leq M$ (for all $\tau$), then I can settle the second term (and probably this can be done again with conservation of energy, it's not the big problem). The big problem is the first term; how can I show that this is “little”??

Comment: I thought the question was quiet interesting, let me know if I can improve it in some way, maybe provide more details about the context. Or would it be more suitable on Phys.SE ?